# Basic mysql to JSON with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I try to create dataTable with php/JSON ... I have this php code:

```
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') { 
    try {
      /* Establish the database connection */

      $array = $db->query("SELECT naziv,opis,status,vrsta FROM aktivnosti")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $jsonTable = json_encode($array);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
    }
    else { 
echo 'GRESKA 404';
  }
```

the output is:

```
 {naziv:Priprema, opis:Da se izrzi nadovdnjavanje, status:U pripremi, vrsta:navodnjavanje}
 {naziv:Djubrenje, opis:Vrsi se djubrenje parcele na temp. od oko 12C, status:U toku, vrsta:djubrenje}
 {naziv:Hemijska analiza, opis:Da se izvrsi hemijska analiza, status:U toku,…}
```

but I need to get output like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "naziv": "<strong>Monday</strong></br>01.01",
      "opis": "System Architect",
      "status": "$320,800",
      "vrsta": "2011/04/25",

    },
    {
      "naziv": "<strong>Monday</strong></br>01.01",
      "opis": "System Architect",
      "status": "$320,800",
      "vrsta": "2011/04/25",
    },
    {
      "naziv": "<strong>Monday</strong></br>01.01",
      "opis": "System Architect",
      "status": "$320,800",
      "vrsta": "2011/04/25",
    },
```

what I need to change in my php code?

Sorry for trivial question but i'm beginer to php and developing. Thanks

Comment: Where do all those System Architect strings come from?

Comment: come from mysql , from table 'aktivnosti' where I select naziv,status,opis,vrsta...

Comment: I'm assuming you just need it in the object `data` just do this `$array['data'] = $db->query( ...`

Comment: data is not the same in two cases, i just put this as example

Comment: you need to not use an example then, please use real data so we can determine what you are asking, right now it is not clear.

Comment: again is the same output ... so the format is wrong becouse I need {
  "data": [
    {
      "naziv" ... ... etc.

Comment: ONLY I NEED TO GET RIGHT FORMAT FOR JSON DATA: {
  "data": [
    {
      "naziv" ETC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$array = $db->query("SELECT naziv,opis,status,vrsta FROM aktivnosti")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$output = ['data' => $array];
$jsonTable = json_encode($output);
```

Comment: yes that code give me error in dreamweaver but works fine. Thanks

Comment: Dreamweaver probably doesn't support the PHP 5.4+ short array syntax, i.e. `array(...)` vs `[..]`.